# Which report or plugins show Performance test metrics / KPI?

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I need your help.
Now, I'm researching and using jmeter to test performance.
I find a web which shows many Performance test metrics/KPI. You can view in this link: http://perftestuk.blogspot.com/2013/07/performance-metrics.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eonZ.png)

I want to ask: In jmeter, Which report or plugins show Performance test metrics / KPI in the picture above?

Comment: Jmeter only shows symptom data (response times).  Do you need to show causal data on the use of resources?

Comment: Dear James, I can view Response times on the HTML report of Jmeter. But for the other Key Performance Indicators, such as: Private bytes, Committed memory, Memory pages/second, Page faults/second, etc (You can see in the link above), I don't know which plugin I need to install to see this Indicators. For example, with Garbage collection, should we use plugin JMXMon Sample Collector?
Many thanks

Comment: Pick your favorite systems monitoring solution which supports your application architecture.  Candidates my include Hyperic, use of command line solutions piped to a file, Nagios, Solarwinds, What's Up Gold, .....   You may need a third tool to consolidate timing records and resource measurements for analysis and reporting, R is a good candidate here

Comment: Thank you so much, James. I want to ask: "R is a good candidate here". What is the meaning of R? And in your opinion, we need to use third tools to consolidate timing records and resource measurements for analysis and reporting instead of using JMeter. = If we use only Jmeter and its plugins, we cannot collect all the key performance indicators above, that's right?

Comment: Jmeter is a load thrower.  The value of the performance test is root cause analysis of why something is slow.  In order to achieve that you need to compare slow response times to the resources used at that moment in time to understand the resource scarcity leading to slow response.   R is a statistics package which will allow you to import multiple data sets for analysis and visualization

Comment: Thank you so much, James

Answer (score 1):

The protocol specific metrics like:

- response time
- throughput (number of bytes per second)
- server hits per second
- connect time
- latency

are available via [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

If you need to monitor your server health (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage), collect database and runtime specific metrics you will have to go for JMeter PerfMon Plugin, see [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitri. Before, I have used Perfmon to collect data about CPU, RAM, Network and Disk. But my boss want to know the other indicators so I have to find. I read many article but found only articles about Performance monitor of PC. I have asked my friend who worked on performance testing and she said that Private bytes, Memory pages/second, Page faults/second: we need to see on Client's parameter and Hit ratios, Rollback segment, Top waits, DB locks: we have to see on DB. I feel really complicated :(